# Trying to flash the color of the background of one of my android apps

Tags: android, background

I'm trying to have my app go between 2 background colors and then return back to the original background color this is the code that i tried thinking it would change the background then pause for a quarter of a second and change the color again. Is there someway to do this. I am fairly new to programming and I am still learning this is what I thought would work but I'm open to any suggestions.

```
Bg.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.C1));
try{Thread.sleep(250);}
catch(InterruptedException e){}
Bg.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.C2));
try{Thread.sleep(250);}
catch(InterruptedException e){}
Bg.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.C1));
try{Thread.sleep(250);}
catch(InterruptedException e){}
Bg.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.C2));
try{Thread.sleep(250);}
catch(InterruptedException e){}
Bg.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(BG[C-1]));
```

Comment: Next time, try to format your code before posting :)

Comment: Did you try this?  Is it working?  You have given us some code, but not really posted what your issue is.  Although, that last line looks as though it may not compile (unless you have an array of int's named 'BG' and an int named 'C'.

Comment: The questions from @nicholas "Did you try this? Is it working?" are most relevant. Are you asking 'if it will work', 'is it the best way to do things' or 'why doesn't it work'? In saying that though, I can see it possibly won't work because `Thread.sleep(...)` will block the UI thread preventing realtime updates.

Answer (score 0):

Set a solid colored background (whatever you want, drawable for example), and use an animation to effect it. You can blink it on and off with whatever parameters you wish including speed, fade, repeat count, and so on ... All declaratively defined in a res/anim .xml file.

A tutorial on Android animations is beyond the scope of what I want to write here, but just Google for it. There are examples of almost anything you want.

You can find the Android API demos related to animation here,
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/anim/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use this approach, then I would suggest doing this in a different thread than the UI thread, because I assume this will make the UI thread sleep for 250 millis, and it will thus be unresponsive.  I don't even if this is even allowed and it is possible that the UI thread will throw an exception.

That said, if you are not going to do anything in the catch clause of IntereuptedException than why not use [SystemClock.sleep](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#sleep%28long%29).

Finally, I suggest forgetting this approach and use animations instead, check [Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)